# Wordpress CSS .angled-background transform: initial;

Tags: wordpress, css

I created www.studycraft.net but then noticed that in Internet Explorer the shadow that goes across the background is at an angle (In Safari, FireFox and Chrome it's a straight vertical edge). I asked on the theme's developer's site how can I make it straight and he had told me to add this to my custom css box:

```
.angled-background {
transform: initial;
}
```

(this may have fixed it for Chrome and/or Firefox, I had only really tested it with Safari and IE before having this "transform" property set)

This does seem to be the right element because this is where he fixed another issue where this shadow wasn't always (certain window sizes) wide enough to cover the title and made that text hard to read against the non-shadowed background - my .angled-background actually looks like:

```
.angled-background {
 min-width:1250px;    
display: block;
transform: initial;
}
```

But in any case, this doesn't seem to fix it for IE - the shadow stills has an angle and it even cuts back in at a certain window sizes to make a strange looking corner to the shadow and then looks really bad. Here's a pic:
[image: angle issue in Internet Explorer]

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back again from the theme's developer and he provided the solution - it should be "transform: none" instead of "transform: initial". So the correct code is:

```
.angled-background {
   transform: none;
}
```